# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform

I know that many others had the same problem and there are many question with same subject/title. But none of those solved my problem.

I was using parse for cloud code and Facebook login. But since, parse shut down, I moved my code to back4app.

Here is my Parse initialization after moving to my own server:

```
[Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration> configuration) {
    configuration.applicationId = @"ParseApplicationId";
    configuration.clientKey = @"ParseClientKey";
    configuration.server = @"https://parseapi.back4app.com";
}]];
```

When I try to login using `PFLogInViewController`, delegate method is called after Facebook login:

```
- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didFailToLogInWithError:(NSError *)error
```

I receive this error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or
>   object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Login with `PFLogInViewController` has nothing to do with my cloud code, as it was completely handled by Parse SDK.

What might be the reason for this error. If you need any further code snippet, I can provide that too.

Thanks

Comment: may be json format is wrong...validate your json and check.

Comment: Hey, check this: https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2016/05/19/parse-pfcloud-json-text-did-not-start-with-array-or-object/, Sounds like it could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it. In my case, my parse initialization was supposed to be like this:

```
[Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration> configuration) {
    configuration.applicationId = ParseApplicationId;
    configuration.clientKey = ParseClientKey;
    configuration.server = @"https://parseapi.back4app.com";
}]];
```

`ParseApplicationId` and `ParseClientKey` were constants and I was passing as string by mistake.

If anyone is using their own server to host parse cloud server, kindly keep in mind that your server should not block `graph.facebook.com`. My local server allowed `facebook.com` but was still blocking `graph.facebook.com`, and it took more than a day to figure out the solution.

Also, you cannot save `PFUser` like before, you might have to add `useMasterKey` as `true`. These are not related to my question, but I wondered if someone may face these issues.